# Send to Content Based on Age (XX) Entered Into Input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now, I have 2 links that direct the user to 2 different groups of content depending on the links they clicked.  The 2 links are:

```
<a id="q1_one" class="a1" href="javascript:void(0)">I am between ages 25 and 30</a>
<a id="q1_two" class="a2" href="javascript:void(0)">I am between ages 31-50</a>
```

and the content they are directed to are:

```
<div class="if_one">
    <p>This content will display if the user entered ages ages 25-30</p>    
    <p>The user is <strong>XX</strong> years old.</p>
</div>
<div class="if_two">
    <p>This content will display if the user entered ages ages 31-50</p>    
    <p>The user is <strong>XX</strong> years old.</p>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript that makes it work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.a1', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.a1, .a2').hide();
        $('.if_one').show();
    });

$(document).on('click', '.a2', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.a1, .a2').hide();
        $('.if_two').show();
    });
```

I would like to be able to use an `<input />` instead of the 2 anchors.. that way if the user enters the ages 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 it will send to the first group of content, and it will do the same for 31, 32, 33, 34, etc. for the 2nd group of content.

I am also trying to display the age they entered where you see XX in the code. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8z2PS/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an `input` with no button use `blur`

```
<input type='text' id='age' />

$("#age").blur(function() {
    $('.a1, .a2').hide();
    var age = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    if (age < 30)
        $('.if_one').show();
    else
        $('.if_two').show();
});
```

To display the age where XX is, use a styled `span`, not `strong` and add this line inside the `if` block:

```
$('.if_one span').text(age); //obviously change to .if_two for the other span.
```

Comment: @h2ooooooo -- Damn radix, always just passes over me...edited and added.

Comment: I know - I'd probably done the same, but code review is always easier when it's someone elses code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will change the **XX**

```
$("#age").blur(function() {
$('.a1, .a2').hide();
var age = parseInt($('#age').val());
if (age < 30)
{
$('.if_one').show();
$('#a1').text(age);
alert($('#a1').val());
}
else
{
$('.if_two').show();
$('#a2').text(age);
}
});
```

working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8z2PS/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/8z2PS/2/

```
<p>How do I turn this Into an Input Box With a Submit button instead of the links below </p>
<input type="button" id="q1_one" class="a1" value="Submit" /><br />


<br/>Enter your age here:

<input id="inp_age" />

<br /><br /><br />

<div class="if_one">
    <p>This content will display if the user entered ages ages 25-30</p>    
    <p>The user is <strong class="getAge">XX</strong> years old.</p>

    <p><strong>How do I replace XX with the age they put in the box?</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="if_two">
    <p>This content will display if the user entered ages ages 31-50</p>    
    <p>The user is <strong class="getAge">XX</strong> years old.</p>

    <p><strong>How do I replace XX with the age they put in the box?</strong></p>
</div>


$(document).on('click', '.a1', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.a1, .a2').hide();

    if(parseInt($('#inp_age').val())>=31)
        $('.if_two').show();
    else
        $('.if_one').show();

    $('.getAge').html($('#inp_age').val());
    });
```